# Saving text entered by the user in Shared Preferences and using it in another activity

Tags: android, save, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

I am creating an app where the user will be required to enter text. This text will get saved in the app and will be used later when the user receives an SMS. Right now, the app crashes when I click the save button. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Context Context;
AudioManager am;
Button save;
EditText on;
EditText off;
SharedPreferences saved;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    on = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.on);
    off = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.off);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved!",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SMSReceiver.class);
            String[] myStrings = new String[] { on.getText().toString(),
                    off.getText().toString() };
            intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("saved",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("text1", on.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("text2", off.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

SMSReceiver.java:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context Context;
AudioManager am;
SharedPreferences settings;
String text1;
String text2;

public void onEnabled(Context ctx) {
    settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("saved", 0);
    text1 = settings.getString("text1", " ");
    text2 = settings.getString("text2", " ");       
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.Context = context;
    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                if (msgBody.equals(text1)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (msgBody.equals(text2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pv.ilostmyphone/pv.ilostmyphone.Broadcast.SMSReceiver}: java.lang.ClassCastException: pv.ilostmyphone.Broadcast.SMSReceiver
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: pv.ilostmyphone.Broadcast.SMSReceiver
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
03-03 23:06:32.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     ... 11 more
```

**SECOND PROBLEM**

Nothing is happening when the SMS  is received. My MainActivity.java is in the package "pv.ilostmyphone" and SMSReceiver.java is in the package "pv.ilostmyphone.Broadcast". Here is the receiver part in my manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".Broadcast.SMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="pv.ilostmyphone.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is the new intent that I created in the MainActivity.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("pv.ilostmyphone.SMS_RECEIVED");
            String[] myStrings = new String[] { on.getText().toString(),
                    off.getText().toString() };
            intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("saved",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("text1", on.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("text2", off.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Would appreciate it if someone could point out an easier way to do this.

Comment: You're calling startActivity with an explicitly defined class (SMSReceiver) which is a BroadcastReceiver. you shoudl be calling sendBroadcast

Comment: Yeah I changed that, still not working.

Comment: You mean the new intent you created in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes. @dymmeh can you help me out with the second problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This line is the culprit.**
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SMSReceiver.class);

You are making a call from an `Activity` to a `BroadcastReceiver`. Hence, it throws `ClassCastException`.

Send broadcast from your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("packagename.MY_ACTION");    
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In the manifest.xml file, define intent-filter with this broadcast name. In this way, BroadcastReceiver will get called when this particular broadcast is fired.

```
<receiver android:name="ReceiverName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="packagename.MY_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**[EDIT]**
The solution of your second problem lies in the manifest file itself. Add the following action in the list of intent-filter of BroadcastReceiver.

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

Do not forget to add permission to receive SMS in manifest file.

Comment: Yup it's not crashing anymore. But now the SMS part is not working. At least this was sorted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you help me out with this? When I click save, Toast message appears, doesn't crash. But when the SMS is received with the text that the user entered, nothing happens. Appears to be a problem with the variables "text1" and "text2". Would appreciate it if you could go over that part and see if you can find a mistake.

Comment: Second part of answer will do.

Comment: I already had that in my manifest. See the edited part of my question above.

Comment: You need to maintain same name of sharedPreferences. You are storing values in a sharedPreferences "default" and extracting from sharedPreferences "saved".

Comment: Fixed that, stupid mistake. But, still not working :"(

Comment: The intent should be created in MainActivity itself. Save the message in MainActivity and extract it in SMSReceiver. Can you confirm if the control comes to your Receiver when message is received? You can quickly check by printing one Toast.

Comment: I'm sorry it was in the MainActivity only. I have added code to print toast messages whenever an SMS with "text1" or "text2" appears. But they don't. The "Saved!" toast appears so I am assuming the variables do get stored in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Do not assume anything. Print a Toast after if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) { to confirm SMS received.

Comment: Did that, I am getting the toast. Problems lies after that it means.

Comment: Cool. It means control gets there when a message is received. Now move text1 = settings.getString("text1", " ");
    text2 = settings.getString("text2", " ");    under onReceive. Print the contents of text1 and text2 and the message received.

Comment: It's crashing when I click Save now. Gives the same fatal exception as before.

Comment: Okay I added code to print a toast message with text1 as the output but the toast printed a blank. So it can't save the text1 and text2 that the user input for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `startActivity(intent)` with `sendBroadcast(intent)`. It doesn't make sense that you're trying to start an `Activity` with an `Intent` that is mapped to a `BroadcastReceiver` (thus the `CastClassException`).

Comment: Tried it, still crashes whenever I click Save.

Comment: I am having another problem, would appreciate it if you could try helping me out. I have added it above.